# Transferring each elemnt in a text file into an array

Tags: java, arraylist, text-files

I have made this method to take in a file.txt and transfer its elements into an array list.
My problem is, I dont want to transfer a whole line into one string. I want to take each element on the line as string.

```
   public ArrayList<String> readData() throws IOException  {
     FileReader pp=new FileReader(filename);
     BufferedReader nn=new BufferedReader(pp);
     ArrayList<String> data=new ArrayList<String>();
     String line;

     while((line=nn.readLine()) != null){
        data.add(line);
      }
     xoxo.close();
     return data;

    }
```

is it possible ?

Comment: What is an "element"?  You will need to quantify what the input current looks like and what you expectations are for the output, based on that input

Comment: once you showed us what those "elements" look like: do you want to put each element into the same list, just reading the file word by word, or do you want a list for each line? (which then again could be in a list... a list of list so to speak)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about reading the lines, but splitting each line into the single words?

```
while ((line = nn.readLine()) != null) {
    for (String word : line.split(" ")) {
        data.add(line);
    }
}
```

The method `split(" ")` in this example will split the line on each whitespace " " and put the single words into an array.

In case the words in the file are separated by another character (like a comma for example) you can use that too in split():

```
line.split(",");
```

If I may, here is a somewhat easier way to read a text file:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(filename);
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    for (String word : line.split(" ")) {
        data.add(word);
    }
}
```

Well not easier but shorter :)

And one last advice: if you give your variables a more.. readable name like `bufferedReader`  instead of naming them all `nn, pp, xoxo` you might have less problems when the code grows more and more complex later on

Comment: glad it helped! I edited my answer to show you a shorter version

Answer (score 2):

Use split function for String.

```
String line = "This is line";
String [] a = line.split("\\s");// \\s is regular expression for space
```

a[0] = This
a[1] = is
a[2] = line

Answer (score 0):

If by 'Element' you mean each word, then simply changing

```
line = nn.readLine()
```

to

```
line = nn.read()
```

should fix your problem, as the read method will take in every character it reads until it hits a space character in which it will return the processed characters. However if by element you mean each character then the problem is much harder. You will need to read each word and split that string up using any of the various functions Java provides.

Comment: I tried this way but it didnt work my inputs are words and I want to read them word by word just like you mentioned but when i use .read() it asks to change line into an int.

Comment: `read` reads a single character and returns its integer representation. So it doesn't work here.